# How to use std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free for SFINAE?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdatomic

How can I use `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` with SFINAE? I have a class template `MyClass<T>` and I would like to switch between 2 implementations, depending on whether `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` is `true`. This is what I have:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class MyClass {
// Fallback implementation
};

template<typename T>
class MyClass<T, typename std::enable_if<std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free>::type> {
// Optimized implementation using std::atomic
};
```

Now, when I try to create an instance of `MyClass<SomeCustomClass>`, I get a compiler error:

> _Atomic cannot be applied to type 'SomeCustomClass' which is not trivially copyable

It tries to use the template specialization, but instead of using the fallback implementation, it doesn't compile at all. Could someone kindly explain what's wrong here? And how do I get the desired result?

Comment: You can't have a `std::atomic<SomeCustomClass>` where `SomeCustomClass` isn't trivially copyable. That's why you get that error

Comment: I know…but why isn't that just a substitution failure, causing a fallback to the general template?

Comment: In the expression `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` the instantation of `std::atomic<T>` fails (for the non-triviably copyable types), and that's not immediate context, hence the compilation fails. You need to not instantiate `std::atomic<T>` in that case. SFINAE would have worked here if `std::atomic<T>` was legal, but `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` would not be.

Comment: @basteln You also have a problem that `std::atomic::is_always_lock_free` is only available in C++17 and over...

Comment: @Rakete1111 Right. I would use a #ifdef to check for its availability.

Comment: So how do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to delay checking `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` until *after* you know that `T` is trivially copyable. Otherwise, `atomic<T>` is ill-formed.

For that, there's [`std::conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) - which is lazy / short-circuits:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_lock_free_impl
: std::integral_constant<bool, std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free> { };

template <typename T>
using is_lock_free = std::conjunction<
    std::is_trivially_copyable<T>,
    is_lock_free_impl<T>>;
```

Now, this trait will abort early and yield `false_type` if `T` isn't trivially copyable. And if it *is* trivially copyable, then it's valid to instantiate `atomic<T>`, so then we check that trait.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` the instantation of `std::atomic<T>` fails (for the non-triviably copyable types), and that's not immediate context, hence the compilation fails. You need to not instantiate `std::atomic<T>` in that case. SFINAE would have worked here if `std::atomic<T>` was legal, but `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` would not be.

> So how do I get the desired result?

With a custom trait:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass { SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass&) { return *this; } };

template<typename... T>
struct make_void { typedef void type; };

template<typename... T>
using void_t = typename make_void<T...>::type;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct IsAlwaysLockFree
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct IsAlwaysLockFree<T, void_t<typename std::enable_if<!std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value>::type>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct IsAlwaysLockFree<T, void_t<typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value>::type>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free;
};

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class MyClass {
// Fallback implementation
public:
    MyClass(){ std::cout << "Fallback\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
class MyClass<T, typename std::enable_if<IsAlwaysLockFree<T>::value>::type> {
// Optimized implementation using std::atomic
public:
    MyClass(){ std::cout << "Optimized\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<SomeClass> a;
    MyClass<std::array<int, 1024>> b;
    MyClass<int> c;
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4af0411b2a4f3302)